# Regular Expression String followed by digits in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting myArray as null. Can anyone help me?

```
myRe = new RegExp ("[A-Z]+(\\d+)");
myArray = myRe.exec("book1");
alert(myArray.length);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regular expression is case sensitive; try:

```
myRe = new RegExp ("[A-Za-z]+(\\d+)");
```

or:

```
myRe = new RegExp ("[A-Z]+(\\d+)", "i");
```

Comment: Or add an i parameter: new RegExp('foo', 'i');

Comment: My fault I was using RegexBuddy with Case Insensitive mode turned on. Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use [A-Z] which is for uppercase.

Use this instead:

```
pattern = /[a-z](\d+)/i;
myArray = pattern.exec("BOOK1");
alert(myArray.length);
```